# My chance to shape our development process/policy

Tags: agile, policy, sdlc

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate, but the question search terms are pretty generic.

I work at a small(ish) development firm.  I say small, but the company is actually a fair size; however, I'm only the second full-time developer, as most past work has been organized around contractors.

I'm in a position to define internal project process and policy- obvious stuff like SCM and unit-testing.  Methodology is outside the scope of the document I'm putting together, but I'd really like to push us in a leaner (and maybe even Agile?) direction.

I feel like I have plenty of good practice recommendations, but not enough solid motivation to make my document the spirit guide I'd like it to be.  I've separated the document into "principles" and "recommendations".  Recommendations have been easy to come up with.  Use SCM, strive for 1-step, regularly scheduled builds, unit test first, document as you go...  Listing the principles that are supposed to be informing these recommendations, though, has been rough.

I've come up with "tools work for us; we should never work for tools" and a hazy clause aimed at our QA (which has been overly manual) that I'd like to read "tedium is the root of all evil".

I don't want to miss an opportunity with this document to give us a good in-house start and maybe even push us toward Agile.  What principles am I missing?

EDIT 4/15 -

I might have been ambiguous about the scope of this document.  For now, it's policy that my co-dev and I plan to follow.  So far, we've been given free reign on choice of local tool, source control, etc, and the general process we follow in development (eg build, deploy, whether to use continuous integration...).

Ideally, I'd also like this document to be a model on which to base further process improvements.  I'm mostly thinking QA, and maybe nudging our project management towards something lighter and iterative.

Comment: I don't fully understand the scope of your document, but I have one strong recommendation: "Code Complete" by Steve Mcconnell. I think it is an invaluable source for principles and recommendtions, and there you might find the principles you're looking for.

Comment: On the meta-level, we need to know your firm's stability/auditability requirements before we can advise with process.

Comment: @Paul Stability/auditability requirements?  If you mean the stability of our projects- well, we aren't building rockets.  We do enterprise-type software, web development, and a variety of other things.  We need to be as stable as makes an individual customer happy, and that changes per product.  I've noticed that we sometimes have trouble with customer expectations, but other times, we don't.  I'm not sure about auditability, but I haven't heard about third party auditing.  If you mean internally, we're a little too small for that, I think.

Comment: @M.A. I edited to better explain document scope.  Let me know if I need to do a better job =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Agile Manifesto](http://agilemanifesto.org/) and [its principles](http://agilemanifesto.org/principles.html) might help with a few more ideas

Comment: I'm going to mix some of the ideas from Pragmatic Programmer's with the Agile Manifesto.  I'll post how it works out, and if I find any other good sources.

Comment: Another book you should read if you have not: The Mythical Man Month.  Mr. Atwood has a not-bad list of books here: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/02/recommended-reading-for-developers.html